# Can a single set of validator keys for staking be signed with multiple Ethereum accounts?

Tags: staking, validators, solo-mining, sepolia

I am setting up solo staking on Sepolia with a local Nimbus client. I want to test a setup where my eth funds are spread out across two ledger devices.

Can I generate a single set of validator keys and then use them to sign deposit transactions from each of the two ledger devices OR do I have to generate two sets of deposit keys and sign each individually with one Ledger device?

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! Have you tried https://github.com/ethereum/staking-deposit-cli ? It should be able to and feel free to post your own answer with what you find out.